# Difference between Cloud to Device and Device to Cloud in Google GCM

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to build a chat application with the Google Cloud Messaging, something similar to whatsapp. Do i need to use 'CCS: Upstream and downstream (device-to-cloud, cloud-to-device)' OR 'GCM HTTP: Downstream only: cloud-to-device' would work just fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GCM HTTP is easier to use and supports Cloud to Device messaging. If all you need is for your server to notify your app when a new message is available, GCM HTTP is enough.

The Cloud Connection Server is only required if you want your app to send messages to your server via its connection to the GCM servers. It's useful if your app needs to send a lot of messages to your server.

Comment: Thanks. so which would you recommend for a chat application like whats app or a dual player turn game?

Comment: @SolomonUbaniDKing I'd start with GCM HTTP. CCS is more complicated to implement, and it's new, so it might still have bugs. The advantage of CCS is supposed to be higher performance and saving battery life (you can use an existing connection for messages from your device to your server, instead of opening your own connection). I wouldn't use it unless my GCM HTTP solution isn't good enough.